# How I can make correct route with button in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have show.blade.php and have button share to go to share.blade.php

this is my show.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')

<div class="container">
    <form method="post" action="/student/share-approval/{{$approval->uniid}}">
     @csrf
      <p> Hello  Trst show page , If you click share butoon should show the share page</p><br>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> share </button>
     </body>
    </form>
  </div>
@endsection
```

and this is my share.plade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')

 <div class="container">
    <form method="post" action="/sendemail">
      @csrf
      <p> Share page</p>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">send </button><br>
  </form>
</div>
@endsection
```

and this is my route in web

```
Route::post('/student/share','StudentController@shareapproval');
Route::get('/student/show-approval/{uniid}','StudentController@showapproval');
Route::get('/student/share-approval/{uniid}', 'StudentController@shareapproval');
```

and this my function in StudentController

```
 public function showapproval($uniid)
{
  $approval = Student :: where ('uniid', $uniid)->firstOrFail();
   return view('ApprovalStudent.Request.show',compact('approval'));
}
   public function shareapproval($uniid)
   {
   $approval = Student :: where ('uniid', $uniid)->firstOrFail();
   return view('SendEmail.Request.share',compact('approval'));
   }
```

the error is (Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
No message)

Comment: try to change your routes;
`Route::post('/student/share','StudentController@shareapproval');
Route::get('/student/show-approval/{uniid}','StudentController@showapproval');
Route::get('/student/share-approval/{uniid}', 'StudentController@shareapproval');`
to; 
`Route::any('/student/share','StudentController@shareapproval');
Route::any('/student/show-approval/{uniid}','StudentController@showapproval');
Route::any('/student/share-approval/{uniid}', 'StudentController@shareapproval');`
and let me know if it works

Comment: If you want to post data to a route (like your form), define the route as `Route::post()` instead of `Route::get()`.

Comment: I make it as this Route::any('/student/share','StudentController@shareapproval'); Route::any('/student/show-approval/{uniid}','StudentController@showapproval'); Route::post('/student/share-approval/{uniid}', 'StudentController@shareapproval'); becouse the share pafe have form to send it via email .... Thank you

Comment: be wary though, do not simply use Route::any. i was stating it as an example to debug. now that you know its the first two routes with the issue, change it to post/get based on what it wasnt previously.

Answer (score 0):

Change the method to `post`

```
  Route::post('/student/share','StudentController@shareapproval');
  Route::get('/student/show-approval/{uniid}','StudentController@showapproval');
  Route::post('/student/share-approval/{uniid}', 'StudentController@shareapproval');
```

Answer (score 0):

As **method** is **post** in this form

```
<form method="post" action="/student/share-approval/{{$approval->uniid}}">
```

make your route **POST** as

```
Route::post('/student/show-approval/{uniid}','StudentController@showapproval');
```

and catch **request** in  **controller** as

```
public function showapproval(Request $request,$uniid)
{

  $approval = Student :: where ('uniid', $uniid)->firstOrFail();
   return view('ApprovalStudent.Request.show',compact('approval'));
}
```

and as good habit use **url()** in action as,

```
<form action="{{url('/')}}/student/share-approval/{{$approval->uniid}}">
```